# Oracle SQL : Extracting data by splitting through delimiter in the query

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a string format of `MID: ABC-123212-2 - SID: 21354` in a column.

Expected result: `ABC-123212-2` and `21354`.

Have tried

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('MID: ABC-123212-2 - SID: 21354', '\d[0-9-]*', 1, 1) FROM DUAL;

SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('MID: ABC-123212-2 - SID: 21354', '\d[0-9-]*', 1, 2) FROM DUAL;
```

But the result is only getting the number.

How can I include the letters also, splitting the data by `:` and middle `-`

Comment: @partycoder i needed to extract the values after ":"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you what you want and it can handle any white spaces in between fields and separators.

**To see how this regex works, see [regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/33JcHm/1)**

To see how this query works, see [dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=85eb069ca97977053dab56929db5aa32)

```
select
regexp_replace(col1,'MID:\s*(\S+).*SID:\s*(\S+).*','\1') as field1
,regexp_replace(col1,'MID:\s*(\S+).*SID:\s*(\S+).*','\2') as field2
from 
(select 'MID: ABC-123212-2 - SID: 21354' as col1 from dual);
```

Output

```
FIELD1          FIELD2
ABC-123212-2    21354
```

**Explanation:**

Regex `MID:\s*(\S+).*SID:\s*(\S+).*` uses 2 capturing groups, enclosed in braces`()`. So after `MID:` we will capture first group, and after `SID:`, we will capture next.

Now `regexp_replace` can return any capturing group from regex. So `\1` and `\2` are use in 2 result set.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` for this, you can just use basic string functions:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(col, 6, INSTR(col, '- SID:') - 7) AS term1,
    SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, 'SID:') + 5)      AS term2
FROM yourTable
```

In most cases, I would expect a solution involving the base string functions to outperform a regex based solution.  This is not to say that regex does not have a time and place, but for something as simple as your extraction I might not use it.

As usual, I couldn't get an Oracle demo working in either Rextester or SQLFiddle, but follow the link below for a MySQL demo.  The string functions `INSTR()` and `SUBSTR()` behave almost the same in Oracle and MySQL, so the logic is still valid.

## Demo

Comment: We can use [dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2) as well, but it is not as robust as sqlfiddle, as `dual` and couple of other stuff doesn't work here, and you have to create a table and insert data to it before testing the query. But a good alternative in case nothing else works.

Comment: @Utsav Thanks, I'll take a look at this next time.